# error: use of undeclared identifier 'avcodec_free_frame'; did you mean 'avcodec_get_name'? avcodec_free_frame(&picture);

Tags: opencv

Trying to install open cv and this erro came up

error: use of undeclared
      identifier 'avcodec_free_frame'; did you mean 'avcodec_get_name'?
        avcodec_free_frame(&picture);
how do I resolve this?